# How to generate Typescript types for queries including Apollo @client and @rest directives using Apollo tooling?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have a client-side schema in `src/schema.graphql` and some queries in `src/graphql/queries.ts`.

Currently, all my queries include [@rest directive from apollo-link-rest](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/#rest-directive) and I am trying to generate Typescript types for them using `apollo client:codegen` with the following command:

```
apollo client:codegen ./src/__generated__/types.ts --outputFlat --includes=./src/**/queries.ts --addTypename --localSchemaFile=./src/schema.graphql --target=typescript
```

This always results in

```
.../src/graphql/queries.ts: Unknown directive "rest".
ToolError: Validation of GraphQL query document failed
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. According to [the docs here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/references/apollo-config/#clientclientonlydirectives-clientclientschemadirectives) Apollo should support `@client` and `@rest` client-side directives out of the box.

Has anyone successfully generated types for queries with `@rest` or `@client` directives?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, a bunch of documentation pages later and it seems if I declare the directive in `src/schema.graphql` as follows, it seems to work:

```
directive @rest(
    type: String!
    path: String!
    method: String
) on FIELD
```

Note: this declaration does not include all possible arguments. Refer to the [docs for the complete list of arguments](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/#arguments).

Can anyone confirm that this is the correct way of doing this?